# Different while loops (do while vs infinite while), which is better?

Tags: c, performance, while-loop, infinite-loop, do-while

which of these codes is better?

```
do {
 fread( ... );
 if(!feof(fp)) { ... }
}
while(!feof(fp));
```

or

```
while(1){
  fread( ... );
  if(!feof(fp)) { ... }
  else break;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I will go with first one.. as infinite loops are dangerous!

Comment: `fread` doesn't work like that...

Comment: what do you mean, how it should work?

Comment: Hmm, no, the other one: `for (;;) {}`

Comment: You should probably check the output of fread(). And I believe for(;;) is faster as it doesn't have to evaluate anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["while( !feof( file ) )" is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. You are better off making the eof test part of the loop condition (at the top).

<s>You can do this:</s>

```
while (!feof(fp)) {
    fread(...);
}
```

Since `fread` returns the number of objects read, you <s>could</s> should also do it this way:

```
while (fread(...) != 0) {
}
```

Comment: while(fread(...) !=0) worked.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop is better since the `do while` do the same operations but it's calling the `feof()` function twice.

Comment: You shouldn't call the function twice as it could be changing! You could declare a variable to store the returned value to check it but the `while` still better

Answer (score 0):

> which is better?

No one is better than another. The only difference in between these two that first one iterate at least once.